# Paste into Prompt (i.e. how to focus on prompt)? (chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, clipboard

I'm trying to build an extension.  The first event runs outside of any browser and is triggered by a hotkey.  That hotkey triggers a prompt and the result of that prompt is used query a webpage.

By default I'd like the prompt to be populated form the user's clipboard.  I have enabled all the appropriate permissions.  Is there any way to "focus" on the input box in the prompt window such that "document.execCommand('paste');" will work?

Is there a way to modify the third line of the following javascript to achieve the desired result?

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var result = prompt("enter value");
    document.execCommand('paste');
    alert(result);
 });
```

html

```
<input type="button" value="clickme" id="myButton">
```

Comment: Why do you need to use prompt?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `document.execCommand`, not to mention `prompt`, that means you're running in a browser environment. So your best bet is to implement a simple overlay + modal dialog in the browser, paste the clipboard contents in an input there, and proceed.

And sadly, you can't "focus" on the clipboard: `document.execCommand` already uses the clipboard. The input in a prompt isn't part of the DOM, so it won't respond to javascript manipulation. :(

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to write "focus" on the clipboard, i meant to write "focus on the input box in the prompt window. Edited to reflect that.   I get that chrome (a browser) is running my code, but there is not an active window open at the time of executing the prompt (other than the prompt itself). So I can't use the normal invisible div trick. (or at least don't know how I would).